# How do I get Emacs shell mode to either render (or ignore) my colors instead of printing ASCII codes?

Tags: emacs, colors, ascii

The symptom of the problem looks like "[0m[27m[24m[J[34;1" which on a terminal translates into the color blue.

-A

Comment: A little more info about my config: zsh + GNU emacs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that is currently giving me some success is to redefine the shell function as an ansi term:

```
;; shell-mode
(defun sh ()
  (interactive)
  (ansi-term "/bin/zsh"))
```

Comment: This is a good idea. It also solves the incompatibility of shell-mode with commands like more/less and man.

Comment: Shadows the "real" shell command.  Use term or ansi-term directly instead of hiding the plain shell mode.

Answer (score 31):

I've got the following in my `.emacs`

```
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
```

Comment: The autoload is not necessary in recent version of Emacs (it's autoloaded by default).

Comment: This did help, (color blue appeared) however some ASCII control codes still appeared in the buffer. No doubt there are one or more details to combine with this solution.

Comment: I think that this answer is getting upvotes reflects that it is working on some common platforms for stackoverflow users.  But see also the accepted answer.

Comment: Works for me in bash, so far anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For the "ignore" alternative, put something like "`alias ls=ls`" or "`unset LS_COLORS`" in your `~/.emacs_{bash,tsch,whatever-your-shell-is-called}` file.  This file is executed in all subordinate shells created by emacs.

> [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Interactive-Shell.html) sends the new shell the contents of the file `~/.emacs_shellname` as input, if it exists, where `shellname` is the name of the file that the shell was loaded from. For example, if you use bash, the file sent to it is `~/.emacs_bash`. If this file is not found, Emacs tries to fallback on `~/.emacs.d/init_shellname.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work in your .bash_profile or .bashrc

```
case $TERM in
xterm-color)
export PS1='\[\e]0;\W\007\]\[\e[34;1m\]\W\[\e[0m\]\$ '
;;
*)
export PS1='\W\$ '
;;
esac
```

Comment: Maybe don't hardcode the color codes; use `tput`