# Ugly ipython prompt on emacs 23

Tags: emacs, ipython, putty

I have a PuTTY terminal running emacs 23. I just installed python-mode.el-6.1.2 and pinard-Pymacs-5989046. The IPython shell looks like this:

> IPython 1.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
>   ?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
>   %quickref -> Quick reference.
>   help      -> Python's own help system.
>   object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
>
> ^[[0;32mIn [^[[1;32m2^[[0;32m]: ^[[0m

Whereas when I run ipython from bash, I get

> IPython 1.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
>   ?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
>   %quickref -> Quick reference.
>   help      -> Python's own help system.
>   object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
>
> In [1]:

Does this look like a charset issue in my PuTTY setup or should I try to find the issue within emacs/python-mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: add this line to ~/.emacs.d/init.el:

> (ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a broken ansi-color-filter

Please check if it happens also with current trunk from

https://launchpad.net/python-mode

Please follow up at:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1238481

Comment: Thanks. I tried to reproduce it at home with the current trunk and I got the same results as you did (with the 4 "In:" blank lines, but working properly). Will try trunk tomorrow with the original setup and report on results. :)

Comment: Problem persists, see bugreport.

Comment: Not a python-mode bug. I get the same weird behaviour in shell mode. :(

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256264/how-do-i-get-emacs-shell-mode-to-either-render-or-ignore-my-colors-instead-of)